# How do I root my Vodafone Smart 4 Power?

Tags: applications, rooting, root-access, installation

I want to install some software like Cheat Engine on my Vodafone 985N (specifications are [here](http://www.gsmarena.com/vodafone_smart_4_power-6508.php)) and they require rooting my phone.I heard that is very dangerous and I can brick my phone if I make a mistake,so I'm scared...I don't even know how to root it and searching on the internet for instructions is also pretty dangerous because the process of rooting is different from one device to another (I think...).So,if anyone succedded in rooting this phone (or others) please give me some step-by-step instructions and (if anything occurs) some sort of "escape" option,instead of bricking or breaking a part of the operating system.Thanks!

Comment: First of all: If you have a full backup (meaning a backup image of all your partitions, most important: efs or similar) then you might want to search through http://www.xda-developers.com for your phone. Also "Cheat Engine" like on PC does not work on Android because nearly all actions you do in any major game are checked and if you say you'd like to buy something that cost 1million gold and you use Cheat Engine to cheat the money for it, the server will simply say: "You don't have enough money". And will kick you from the game.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Your question, as it stands, is very opinion based. It is ok to as "How do I root my Vodafone Smart 4 Power" as that will have factual steps, but "is it a good idea", that will be based solely on opinion. See the [help center](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/) for [how do I ask a good question](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to stay [on topic](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)